# Dependency is present in MANIFEST.MF, but still get NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, linux, maven

I used the `maven-assembly-plugin` to put all my dependencies into a `lib` folder - I can confirm that the required dependency `jar` is inside the `lib` folder.

I am using `maven-jar-plugin` with the following snippet to link with the dependencies in the `lib` folder:

```
<configuration>
    <archive>
        <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
            <mainClass>my.main.class.MainClass</mainClass>
        </manifest>
    </archive>
</configuration>
```

I used `jd-gui.exe` to decompile my `jar` and I can see that the `MANIFEST.MF` file contains my dependency as `lib/MyLibFile.jar`.

However, when I try to run my app in a Linux environment like so:

`java -cp MyApp.jar my.class.app.MainClass ...`

I get `NoClassDefFoundError`. However, if I do the following:

`java -cp MyApp.jar:lib/* my.class.app.MainClass ...`

The app runs.

Could someone please point why `MyApp.jar` cannot read the dependent library file during runtime?

**Update:**

Tried with `java -jar MyApp.jar` and this is also not working. I believe something is wrong with my `MANIFEST.MF` but I cannot find the issue.

**EDIT:**

The following is my simplified `MANIFEST.MF` -

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: dev
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_25
Class-Path: lib/LibA.jar lib/LibB.jar lib/MyLibFile.jar
Created-By: Apache Maven
Main-Class: my.main.class.MainClass
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
```

Project directory structure:

```
 lib/
 config/
 MyApp.jar
```

Content of `lib` directory:

```
LibA.jar
LibB.jar
MyLibFile.jar
```

My dependency is in the `MyLibFile.jar`.

I run my app by first `cd` into my project directory, then from there I execute `java -jar MyApp.jar`

This is the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dependency/lib/path/ClassName
        at my.class.path.MyApp.main(MyApp.java:65)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dependency.lib.path.ClassName
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 1 more
```

Comment: `lib/MyLibFile.java` isn't a useful CLASSPATH entry, and it isn't what you should see in a manifest generated by the above XML. It should name .class or .jar files.

Comment: Why not run it as `java -jar MyApp.jar`?

Comment: @EJP Thank you for pointing that out, it was a typo, I do have the dependency as `MyLibFile.jar`

Comment: @RobertScholte My group has several other projects all run like so. The question is, why is this not working in my case?

Answer (score 1):

```
java -cp MyApp.jar my.class.app.MainClass
```

The above command doesn't care about the manifest of the jar file. It explicitely sets the classpath to MyApp.jar **only**, and asks to run the class `my.class.app.MainClass` instead of the main class set in the manifest.

To execute an executable jar file (i.e. the main class setin the manifest, with all the dependencies listed in the manifest in the classpath), you must use the `-jar` option instead of the `-cp` option:

```
java -jar MyApp.jar
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. I see a lot of other project in my group being run the same way and they all are using the same dependency library as I am, yet they are all run with the `-cp` option. Is it because they `pom.xml` packaged their binary different from mine? What could be different between our projects that would allow them to run with `-cp` but not mine?

Comment: they probably also pass the library jar file in the -cp option: `java -cp myApp.jar:lib/myLib.jar some.MainClass`

Comment: Then they're probably not actually using the library.

Comment: I just tried with `java -jar MyApp.jar` and this is also not working...I am now clueless...

Comment: Edit your question. Tell us the exact content of the manifest. The content of the current directory and its subdirectories. the exact command you launched, and the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: I posted the items you've asked for. Please let me know if you are looking for anything more.

Comment: where is the dependency.lib.path.ClassName located. If it is in MyLibFile.jar, show the result of `jar tvf lib/MyLibFile.jar`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69609/discussion-between-czchlong-and-jb-nizet).